# "ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi" apache error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run a django project on CentOS 7. I have a virtual environment inside my project containing all the required packages, ... . I configured my httpd.conf file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName the_server_ip_address
ServerAlias localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# adding these lines for handling static files
Alias /media/ /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/static/media
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/static/static_root/

<Directory /var/www/html>
#Order allow,deny
#Allow from all
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess localhost processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/walk.venv python-path=/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite
WSGIProcessGroup localhost

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite>
WSGIPassAuthorization On
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
#Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my wsgi.py is configured as follows:

```
import os, sys
# add the mysite project path into the sys.path
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite')

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/wsgi- 
scripts/walk/walk.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# poiting to the project settings
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The httpd is restarting fine, but when I access the website, an "Internal Server error" is returned and there are the following lines inside the apache log:

```
(most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
mod_wsgi (pid=11196): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=11196): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I have stucked in this error for two days and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/walk.venv` is definitely the same as `sys.prefix` for your virtual environment where Django is installed, then the issue is likely that mod_wsgi is compiled for a different version of Python that your virtual environment was created from. You also don't need to be using `site-packages`.

See:

- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

To work out what Python version mod_wsgi is compiled for, see:

- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: Thank you Graham. Your link helped me very much. I ran the following command and I realized that my python-home in the httpd.conf file should be '/usr'.

    python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"

Answer (score 0):

There's a little more to activating a virtualenv than just adding site-packages to the sys.path.

I've personally just executed the activate script right at the top of your wsgi module and it works well. Eg,

```
# Run find . -iname 'activate_this.py' and just paste the path here.
env_file="/var/www/html/wsgi-scripts/walk/walk.venv/bin/activate_this.py"

assert os.path.exists(env_file)

# Run the activation
execfile(env_file, dict(__file__=env_file))
```

That'll do the full path manipulations necessary to run in the virtualenv. Note that I'm asserting the file exists, just because it's easy to mess up paths.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you mean I should add the "env_file" line in my wsgi.py file, right?